# I am not able to work with asynchronous call in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Contact(LoginViewModel objmodel, string returnUrl)
    {
        LoginViewModel model = new LoginViewModel();

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        string mode = "User_Login";
        //string userLoginName = "test";
        //string userPassword = "test";
        string userLoginName = model.UserName;
        string userPassword = model.Password;

        ObjectParameter returnParams = new ObjectParameter("Params", typeof(string));
        DBECRF_01Entities3 ent = new DBECRF_01Entities3();

       string outparam = (ent.Sp_UserLogin(mode, userLoginName, userPassword, returnParams)).ToString();

        switch (outparam)
        {
            case "Success":
                return View("Contact");
            case "Failure":
                return View("Lockout");
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }

       // return View("Index", model);
    }
```

This is My Controller method where I want to implement the async method. But unfortunately it gives me a fatal warning:

> This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously.
>   Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls,
>   or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

Like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to create an asynchronous method, you indeed need asynchronous content in it (a call that will require an unknown amount of time to be executed)  like a database call for instance, and use the word **await** in front of it (ad your error message suggests):

```
public async Task<Stuff> GetStuff()
{
   return await db.GetAllStuff();
}
```

If you can't have any asynchronous call inside your method, then the best practive is "not to lie" and leave it as synchronous: in your case, replace

```
async Task<ActionResult>
```

with

```
ActionResult
```

But if you **REALLY** need to, you can add this line:

```
await Task.Delay(100);
```

100 being the time to wait in ms.